# How to use php mysqli query and assign multiple values

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm new to php.I tried to connect db use php mysqli and query multiple values and then assign to new variable.

Code:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','name','password','database name');
mysqli_query($con, "SET character_set_results=utf8,character_set_client='utf8'");
mysqli_query($con, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$sql="SELECT store_web,store_email,store_address1,store_city,store_state,store_zip,store_phone,store_time FROM mystore";
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
  // Fetch one and one row
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
   printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1]);

  }
  mysqli_free_result($result);
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

My question is how should I modify the code so that I can assign new variable name to the value（store_web,store_email,store_address1,store_city,store_state,store_zip,store_phone,store_time） I have queried out?

for example, after query out and get the value of store_address1,$address = store_address1

Comment: What do you mean by "value I have queried out"? What exactly are you trying to achieve, can you give a bit more context?

Comment: Thank you for your reply,I want to get the value of (store_web,store_email,store_address1,store_city,store_state,store_zip,store_phone,store_time) and assign a assign new variable to them.for example,after query out and get the value of store_address1,$address = store_address1

Comment: you already have such variables. just use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` and then you will have all variables in this form `$row['store_address1']`

Comment: @YourCommonSense thank you for your reply, I think you gives the right answer, can you post it as an answer so that I can check it?Thank you so much!

Comment: No need for the new answer, there are existing ones

Comment: Thank you I got it!